# Correct way to pass 'this' to function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My javascript is pretty basic so I though I'd ask the experts as to whether my current method is right or not, and if there are better, more accepted ways.

Normally I would use jquery's .on event to trigger a function, like this:

```
$("body").on("input", "textarea", textareaAutoGrow);

function textareaAutoGrow() {
    var pad = $(this).outerHeight(false) - $(this).innerHeight();

    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + pad) + "px";
}
```

This way, 'this' is passed automatically, however I now need to do the same thing on the window resize event for all textareas, not just one specific one.

Here's how I've done it:

```
$(window).on("resize", refreshAutoGrow);

function refreshAutoGrow() {
        $el = $(".text-field.autogrow").filter(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        });

        $el.each(function () {
            textareaAutoGrow.call(this);
        });
    }
```

I've called the textareaAutoGrow function using .call - something I picked up from looking at jquery widgets.

It works but as I said, it's very much a guess - is this the right approach, or are there more accepted ways of doing what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger it with `each` on resize to loop the textareas:

```
function textareaAutoGrow() {
    var pad = $(this).outerHeight(false) - $(this).innerHeight();

    this.style.height = "auto";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + pad) + "px";
}

$("body").on("input", "textarea", textareaAutoGrow);
$(window).on("resize", funtion() {
    $("textarea").each(textareaAutoGrow);
});
```

Comment: first on("input" will not work on dynamic textareas you need to use the code form the question `$("body").on("input", "textarea"`

Comment: now the second code will not work because `textareas` will hold reference to body.

Comment: Ahh, sure. ;) Dumb me. I removed that part then. It would be overhead to do it in this answer.